# Excel find non matches reverse XMATCH

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365, lookup

I need a formula that finds non-matching entries in array1 with the criteria array2
To make this simple (and as the actual data is confidential)
array1 is {"a";"b";"c";"d";"e"}
array2 is {"b";"c";"d"}
My desired output would be either {"a";"e"} or at least {true; false; false; false; true}
I've tried everything I can think of

Comment: By array, do you mean column?

Comment: in this case yes

Answer (score 0):

OK I thought i had tried everything

This worked

```
=LET(
array1,{"a";"b";"c";"d";"e"},
array2,{"b";"c";"d"},
s,SEQUENCE(ROWS(array1)),
nomatch,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(INDEX(array1,s),array2,0))=TRUE,s,""),
INDEX(array1,FILTER(nomatch,nomatch<>""))
)
```

Comment: `=LET(array1,{"a";"b";"c";"d";"e"},array2,{"b";"c";"d"},nomatch,ISERROR(MATCH(array1,array2,0)),FILTER(array1,nomatch))` No need for all the extra steps.